# Using Linq to return a Comma separated string

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class in my application

```
public class ProductInfo
{
  public int ProductId {get;set;}
  public int ProductType{get;set;}
}
```

I want to write a linq query which can return me a list of ProductIds in a comma separated format where ProductType is equal to certain number ?

I tried using string.join with my Linq statement but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 278, accepted):

```
var s = string.Join(",", products.Where(p => p.ProductType == someType)
                                 .Select(p => p.ProductId.ToString()));
```

Comment: Not even 1 minute completed :)

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I know many people here always try to answer as quickly as possible :), I'm just a learner compared to them :)

Comment: How would you select multiple columns?

Comment: @DougDexter not sure what you meant in this context. The OP's question is fairly specific about obtaining a string with some values separated by commas. So the result in `Select` should be a `string` or otherwise the `ToString()` on each item will be called to get a string. If you select multiple properties (as understood by you as columns), those properties still need to be combined somehow to make a string. So that's the unclear point. It depends more on how you want the data to be shaped.

Comment: @jazzBox to select multiple columns, try the following: 
string.Join(",", products.Where(p => p.ProductType == someType)
                                 .Select(p => $"ID: {p.ProductId.ToString()} Name: {p.ProductName.ToString()}"));