# How can I write a LINQ query which will coalesce column values in a DataTable into a comma delimited string?

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

I have a DataTable in a VB.Net application.

I would like to come up with a LINQ expression which would allow me 
for a give column, take that column value from each row in the DataTable
and coalesce it into a comma separated string.

Consider a DataTable with rows that look like:

```
RowID  Value
============
1      A
2      B
3      C
4      D
5      E
6      F
```

The desire result "A,B,C,D,E,F"

I know I could iterate over the rows to create this result.
My question is,

Can I do this with a simple LINQ query?

Thanks,
JohnB

Comment: Are you talking about a `DataTable` as the decade old class?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18991390/1659563)

```
var s = string.Join(",", products.Where(p => p.ProductType == someType)
                                 .Select(p => p.ProductId.ToString()));
```